# springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize

Tags: spring-boot, exception, redis, serializable, redis-cache

I have a problem with Redis Cash. When I try call method `getById` I get:

> Action.handleValidationException.error validate exception:
> org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize

Each of my entities extends `BaseEntity`. And all DTO entities are records. Every entity implements `Serializable`.
How to fix this problem?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

}
```

```
    @Service
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    @EnableCaching
    public class UniversityServiceImpl implements UniversityService {

    private final UniversityRepository universityRepository;
    private final UniversityMapper universityMapper;

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "getById",key = "#id")
    public UniversityResponseDTO getById(Long id, String lang) {
        log.info("Action.getById.start");
        University university = universityRepository.getById(id);
        log.info("Action.getById.end");
        return universityMapper.toUniversityResponseDTO(university, lang);
    }
}
```

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableRedisRepositories
    public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Value("${redis.host}")
    private String host;


    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, 6379);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
    }


    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return template;
    }
    }
```